# Are two objects related by symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetry

This is for computer learning tic tac toe. Given the symmetry operations - flip about vertical axis, flip about horizontal axis, flip about diagonal (transpose), rotate 90 degrees)  - I need to determine if two board configurations are equivalent, i.e. related by symmetry and, if so, what is the transformation from one to the other.

I guess I need group theory and my question is where to begin reading.

Comment: There are 8 possible operations. Just try them all, one by one?

Comment: I think I would have to try all combinations of operations, as two boards may not be related in a single step, right?

Comment: No need. The combination of any two of the 8 operations gives you another of the 8 operations.

Comment: You shouldn't need much group theory. I think the best way is to use permutation on the 8 squares (since the centre is always fixed). Label your squares 1 to 9 and define your transformations as a sequence of transpositions (pretty straightforward for the reflections) .